# Substituting R code chunks in the middle of a large expression dynamically/conditionally

Tags: r

I wonder if there is a functionality in R where details of complicated expressions can be modified conditionally - without repeating the whole computations with minor modifications in another if-loop. I pseudo-code i want to so something like (e.g. having a switch for the multicore-functionality - but this is merely an example):

```
if (a) {startcluster = "cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores() - 1);
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores() - 1);"}
else{startcluster = " "}
eval(parse(text=paste(startcluster, sep = "")))
# this part works already :-)

# now comes the hard part:    
if (a) {my_operator = "%do%"}
else {my_operator = "%dopar%"}

foreach(some_expression) my_operator {
some_calculations}
```

followed by a conditional

```
stopcluster = "stopCluster(cl);"
eval(parse(text=paste(stopcluster, sep = "")))
```

which works already.

What i am looking for is a way to change an operator "my_operator" in the middel of a large piece of code, this way changing the way the code works. Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Side note: You can't put an `else` on a seperate line if you've already finished the `if` statement.  You need to have the closing parenthesis for the if be at the start of the line for the else statement.

Comment: Thanks, my r skills are a bit rusty, I have indeed forgotten this detail.

Comment: Your edit would be better suited for a new question.  But it basically comes down to how things end up being parsed.  If you can finish the parsing and start executing code at the end of the if block then the else needs to be on the same line as the closing brace.  If you're inside of another if statement or a loop or a function... something where you don't immediately execute the code as soon as it is finished being read in by the interpreter then you can have it on a separate line.  I personally don't like to do that since it's only allowed in certain situations and can bite you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dason! ...and you're right:  If that's okay for you I'll put it into a separate question and copy your answer. Or do you prefer to answer yourself?

Comment: Put up a new question (although actually I'm like 99% sure there is already a question for this so it would probably get closed as a duplicate) and wait for answers - you'll get some that are probably better than my explanation. But like I said it's probably a duplicate anyways..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the syntax to create a binary operator and you need to use backticks to prevent unwanted parsing.

```
if(a){
  `%my_operator%` <- `%do%`
}else{
  `%my_operator%` <- `%dopar%`
}
```

Comment: Or `\`%my_operator%\` <- if (a) \`%do%\` else \`%dopar%\``

Comment: Very nice! After the definition I simply use %my_operator% after the foreach-parenthesis. It works as desired, thank you very much!

Comment: @Frank Yeah that works. I tend to prefer the format I wrote. It might be longer and it might duplicate a little bit of code but it's just my preference. I tend to think of `if` as more of a control-flow structure rather than the function that it is so I don't typically use the `value <- if(blah) x else y` design pattern much but there isn't any harm in it.

Comment: Fair enough. I think of it as a poor man's ternary operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: @Frank I guess one could do something like `\`%?%\` <- function(e1, e2){if(e1) e2[1] else e2[2]}` and use it like `val <- TRUE %?% c("val if true", "val if false")` to get an even more mangled version of the ternary operator

Comment: Thanks, yup :) I've thought through many angles on it. I'm not really a fan of the %fun% syntax that's necessary for binary operators... if it were nicer, I'd define my own ternary operator, set union and intersection and probably many more. I find it hard to read %fun% at a glance...